# python matplotlib live graph x axis gets squeezed as more data comes in

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, matplotlib-widget, livegraph

'''
 - Hello Everyone, i have a small issue any help is really appreciated,
   i have a hardware which captures temperature and humidity i am using
   python to display live graph

problem: after 10 seconds x-axis get flooded with time please see
   photo to get a clear picture of the problem

how do I get rid of this issue  x-axis is not cleared as new and new
   data comes in time is squeezed on the x-axis.

also, I have a function that add data to database I want to add that
   data after every 10 sec time. sleep doesn't work

'''

```
 import serial
 import sqlite3
 import datetime
 import time
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 from matplotlib import style
 import matplotlib.animation as animation
 from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import 
 FigureCanvasTkAgg ,NavigationToolbar2Tk
 import threading
 style.use('ggplot')
 fig=plt.figure()
 ax1=fig.add_subplot(111)
 x_axis=[]               # time in str
 y_axis_t=[]             # contains live data from sensor
 y_axis_h=[]  

 def add_db(time,t,h,dt):
    conn=sqlite3.connect('Temperature.db')
    c=conn.cursor()

    c.execute("""
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS data 
    (Time TEXT,Temperature TEXT,Humidity TEXT,Date TEXT)""")

    c.execute(""" INSERT INTO data
    (Time, Temperature, Humidity, Date)
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)""", (time, t, h, dt))

    conn.commit()
    c.close()
    conn.close()

def read_data():
arduinodata =serial.Serial('COM8',9600,timeout=0.1)
while arduinodata.inWaiting:
    val=arduinodata.readline().decode('ascii')
    if len(val) == 13 :
        return val

def process():

    h,t=read_data().split(',')

    mytime = datetime.datetime.now()
    tm= '{}:{}:{}'.format(mytime.hour,mytime.minute,mytime.second)
    dt= '{}/{}/{}'.format(mytime.month,mytime.day,mytime.year)

    print(tm,str(t),str(h),str(dt),end='')


    x_axis.append(tm)
    y_axis_t.append(t)
    y_axis_h.append(h)

    return tm,str(t),str(h),str(dt)

def animate(i):


    ax1.clear()
    tm,t,h,dt=process()


    # i want to convert x axis time to timestamp how ?
    ax1.plot(y_axis_t,label='Temperature',color='r')
    ax1.fill_between(x_axis, y_axis_t, color='r', alpha=0.2)


    # i want to convert x axis time to timestamp how ?
    ax1.plot(x_axis,y_axis_h, label='Humidity',color='b')
    ax1.fill_between(x_axis, y_axis_h, color='b', alpha=0.2)

    for label in ax1.xaxis.get_ticklabels():
        label.set_rotation(45)

    plt.xlabel('Time ')
    plt.ylabel('Temperature in C and Humidity in %')
    plt.title('DHT-11 Sensor Graph ')
    plt.legend()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ani=animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=1000)
  plt.show()
```

[Problem can be seen in figure how x axis gets squeesed as more data come in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHw5q.gif)

Comment: So are you trying to remove data as new data is coming in? If so, what data?

Comment: You forgot to convert your strings to actual dates.

Comment: If you convert the string into date time you cant plot in matplot lib as plot function takes arguments as string one solution can be i keep a counter if that counter is greater than 10 pop the element in that list another solution can be set limit of x axis first pop solution didnt worked for me second one did